# What remedies are there for percieved color artifacts due to pixel geometry?

Tags: color, artifacts

I have a white line on black background. Because of the pixel geometry the line does not look really white; one edge looks red-isch, the other blue-isch. Other fore- and background yield other sensations. Pixel geometry is striped RGB, DPI is ~90, viewing distance about an arms length.

Is there any software based solution or maybe visual design that makes this less appearant, assuming we know the screen pixel geometry in advance?

Comment: Could you specify if your line is font (text) rendering or something you draw yourself some other way?

Comment: @Olivier Both line and text actually rendered using OpenGL, though the effect is most appearant for lines aligned to pixel grid in the direction of the striped pixel geometry.

Answer (score 1):

In computer typography, the technique for adjusting strokes so that they align with the pixel grid is called [hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting).

The color artifacts you are seeing are due to another technique called [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).